With use transpilePackages, unable to Import Components from Another Package in Next.js 14 Monorepo
I am currently using Next.js 14 with a monorepo structure.
The repository is organized as follows:
test-mono-repo
├── package.json
└── packages
    ├── test-console -> Next.js 14
    └── test-ui      -> React 18

I want to use React components from the /packages/test-ui project in the /packages/test-console package.
However, I am facing an issue where I cannot import components from @test/ui, even though I have set up the configuration as follows.
Current Configuration
test-mono-repo/package.json
{
  "name": "test-mono-repo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/test-ui",
    "packages/test-console",
  ],
  ...
}

packages/test-console/next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['.'],
  },
  typescript: {
    tsconfigPath: isDev ? './tsconfig.json' : './tsconfig.build.json',
  },
  distDir: 'dist',
  images: {
    domains: ['cdn.test.com'],
  },
  transpilePackages: ['@test/ui'],
};

export default nextConfig;

packages/test-console/package.json
{
...
"paths": {
      "@test-ui/*": ["./*"]
    }
...
}

Problem:
In the files of the packages/test-console project, I attempted to import as follows:
import { TestComponent } from '@test/ui';

However, the import fails. I want to know if additional settings are needed to use the components with transpilePackages without building.
Questions
What configurations are necessary to correctly import the @test/ui package into @test/console? Are there any additional things I should check?
